# Problem in understanding solution to problem 4a, chapter 22 of Spivak Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In chapter 22 of Spivak calculus, problem 4a is

> Prove that if a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to $l$, then the sequence itself converges to $l$.

This is the solution in Combined answer book

> Since $a_{n_k}$ converges to $l$. There exits $J\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $$
> k>J\Rightarrow |a_{n_k}-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
> $$
>   Since $a_n$ is Cauchy. There exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $$
> n,m>N_1\Rightarrow|a_n-a_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
> $$
>   Let $N=\max(N_1,n_J)$. If $n>N$, then
>   $$
> |a_n-a_{n_{j+1}}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> |a_{n_{j+1}}-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
> $$
>   Consequently $|a_n-l|<\epsilon$.

I do not understand, how when $n>N$, then

$$
|a_n-a_{n_{j+1}}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
and
$$
|a_{n_{j+1}}-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof seems to be incorrect.

> In order to deduce 
>   \begin{align*}
> |a_n-a_{n_{J+1}}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   we have to assure that $n>N_1$ and $n_{J+1}>N_1$.
>
> Since $n>N=\max(N_1,n_J)\geq N_1$ we have $n>N_1$. But we don't know if $n_{J+1}>N_1$.

We know $n_{J+1}>n_J$ which is sufficient to show
\begin{align*}
|a_{n_{J+1}}-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}
but not sufficient to show (1).

Answer (score 0):

Proof goes as follows:

Let $a_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence. 
Suppose that $a_{j_{n}}$ is a convergent subsequence of $a_{n}$.

First, note that the sequence $j_{n} \geq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (You can prove this as an exercise). (*)

We want to proof that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exist a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|a_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ (for some $L$ where $L$ is the limit we want).

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $a_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then exist an $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n \geq N_{1}$, $|a_{n}-a_{m}|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

In the other hand, we have that $a_{j_{n}}$ is convergent (say, to $M$). Then, exist $N_{2}$ such that for all $n \geq N_{2}$, $|a_{j_{n}}-M|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$

If we choose $N_{0}=max(N_{1},N_{2})$, then let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_{0}$.

By (*) we have $j_{n} \geq n \geq N_{0}$. In particular, $j_{n}, n \geq N_{1}$ then, since $a_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence by hypotesis, $|a_{j_{n}}-a_{n}|< \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$

But also $n \geq N_{2}$, then $|a_{j_{n}}-M|< \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

By triangle inequality, we have $$|a_{n}-M|=|(a_{n}-a_{j_{n}})+(a_{j_{n}}-M)|\leq |a_{n}-a_{j_{n}}|+|a_{j_{n}}-M|=|a_{j_{n}}-a_{n}|+|a_{j_{n}}-M|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

In other words: $$|a_{n}-M|<\epsilon$$

And $M$ is the $L$ we wanted at the begin of the proof.